# Unable to create the trigger after installing the salesforce app from the different domain

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforce1-app, appexchange

I have created salesforce lightning app which needs to create trigger dynamically using tooling API.. To work with the tooling API i created connected app with the named credentials and able to create the trigger programatically. Now i packged app and deployed and i shared installation link other user. the other user able to install the app but not able to create the trigger.. it says following error.

```
An internal server error has occurred\nError ID: 1911010353-43716 (119852647)" is the error
```

Can anyone suggest me is this error because of absence of named credentials in installed user domain?

it is working in my domain..

Comment: Are you trying to install this app in Live system?

Comment: I have another domain with another user login. i am installing in that domain.. How to add the named credentials in the package ? can u help me in that

Comment: That error number is unique autonumber, hundreds of things can go wrong during package installing and it will through throw generic error.

One reason I got this was when I tried using Tooling API in production/live environment. Tooling API cant be used only in Sandboxes and developer environment. That being said You have to enable debug logs during instalation and see what error it generates in the target org.

Comment: If tooling API can not be used in production environment then how can i create trigger programmatically .. what if my buisiness requirement is to create trigger dynamically.

Comment: Why do you need to create trigger in production? It doesn't sound all right.. Can you provide the business use case we can provide a solution that might not involve creating trigger in production.

Comment: I would like to select one object , i want to create trigger on that object to do some operations while database operations are happening on that object.

Comment: If you insists, yes you can do that using metaData api. There already exists an app exchange package that does that. You can view its source code to create and Deploy trigger in production. Here is the link of its Github repository. https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries